# Does the T-1000 have a name?

Tags: the-terminator-series, robots, terminator-2-judgment-day

The T-800 are called as Uncle Bob and Pops, these are nicknames, but does the T-1000 have a name? Or is ever called in some way other than its model?

Comment: Neither "Uncle Bob" nor "Pops" are surnames.  They're pseudonyms & nicknames, given to the individual T-800s by humans.  They no actual name of their own.
Like the T-800 in the first film, the T-1000 is simply referred to as the T-1000.

Comment: Not sure if this comment is canon or a good answer. I find it highly unlikely that the SkyNet system does not assign EVERY asset a unique ID number. My guess is, this would be like a model number and unique serial number. For example T-800-1234. This number would be, at the very least, used for identifying an individual "robot" for issuing orders or keeping track of tasks.

Comment: Sure—its name is Austin.

Comment: @HamSandwich, great answer! Why didn't answer in the section below bro?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that SkyNet is sort of a technology *HiveMind* kind of like how ants work together, SkyNet works the same.

> It is the controlling force behind all of the battle units. It pools
>   data from battle units, develops tactics and coordinates attacks.
>   Skynet has control over everything which contains a Cyberdyne Systems
>   CPU.

It seems them as "Units" rather than individual sentient beings

Comment: So do the units have names? And what's the source of your quote?

Comment: No, as i implied by my comment that it does not see them as individual beings. for the quote please check this link: http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Skynet

Thank you for asking this question

Comment: Just my thoughts but you could consider linking your answer back to the OP (i.e. No, the T-1000 does't have a name because each unit is not recognised as an individual, as evidenced by this source), and you could also include the source link just beneath your quote (to easily show others where it came from)